# How do I know if firebase firestore has finished reading data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this piece of code here that grabs the username based on the ID:

```
    DocumentReference df = fstore.collection("Users").document(user.getUid());
    df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                if (doc.exists())
                {
                    username.setText("@"+ doc.get("Username").toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But I noticed that it takes a while to change the username when I run the app. I want to display a progress bar while Firestore is retrieving data and disable it once it's done, how do I know if Firestore has finished grabbing the username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a ProgressBar in your layout file. Assuming you have a ConstraintLayout, you can add it like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

And then find it in your activity class like this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.layout.progressBar)
```

And use it in this way:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) \\ display it.
DocumentReference df = fstore.collection("Users").document(user.getUid());
df.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) \\ hide it.
            DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
            if (doc.exists()) {
                username.setText("@"+ doc.get("Username").toString());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: oh I didnt realize it was that simple, I thought there'd be something like a special method to know that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `inProgress` flag. Set the flag to `true` when you're about to make the call to retrieve the data and set it back to `false` once you're done. Use this flag to know when to display a progress bar (or a load spinner).